# How to block UI for some seconds in android?

Tags: wait, android

How can i block UI from all interactions for some seconds by user in Android?

I would like to know, how to do this with some delay timing like `wait(5000);`

Comment: Never do that it cause ANR. Other  way is use some Progress Dialog for your background work.

Answer (score 9):

You can override [`dispatchTouchEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) and stop the call to `super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);` Any touch event will have to go through this method before it is handled.

Set a boolean that you control and use it in the method to determine whether you wish to block control.

```
private boolean stopUserInteractions = false;

public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (stopUserInteractions) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Comment: You ignore the possibility of keyboard interactions, and also this would have to be implemented statically across all Activities. Best to go the progress dialog approach.

Answer (score 4):

Show `Non-cancelable progress dialog` and close it by code when you want.......

see example

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-threads-and-progressdialog

Answer (score 1):

You can pop up a modal, non-cancelable progress dialog that blocks the user from doing anything. However, you should never block the UI thread itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use ProgressDialog in UI Block time. Set ProgressDialog  cancel-able false. So user do not able to access UI.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As your Question is Short, you will get answer in that manner.

You can use [Thread](http://coopsoft.com/ar/AndroidArticle.html) or [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for making some ProgressDialog being Visible for the User.