# How to lock touches of all screen while Activity Indicator is showing in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, mobile

I have been developing an app in React Native and I'm polishing it. One of my mistakes is that when I show an ActivityIndicator I can touch components of the view that are below of this ActivityIndicator component. 
I've tried put it in a modal view. It works but it seems dirty.
Do you have any other idea about how to lock the touches?

Comment: This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239460/how-to-block-ui-for-some-seconds-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For blocking touches on the entire view I am using https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#pointerevents
However, you might need to explore more for navigation bar action like back and hardware back action.

Comment: Nice, it is what I need. The only problem is that I would have to go putting the prop to all my components. Thanks!

Comment: if your use case involves adding props and handling the disable in every view, I suggest you to make a HOC to control this behavior

Answer (score 3):

You need to make an *overlay* for that and add `pointerEvents="none"` to it as mentioned [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#pointerevents).

**Styles**

```
spinner: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#f3f3f3'
    }
```

**Usage**

```
{loading && <View style={styles.spinner} pointerEvents={'none'}>
        <ActivityIndicator/>
    </View>
}
```

where `loading` is your conditional check.

Comment: this is a nice, simple solution. In my case I had to give my container a width and height of "100%" and a zIndex to bring it up front....worked well

Answer (score 0):

For blocking touches on the entire view I am using [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#pointerevents)
However, you might need to explore more for navigation bar action like back and hardware back action.

this above link is no longer working. here we have a new component which you can use

```
import React from "react";
import { View,ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import { scale } from "react-native-size-matters";
const BlockLoading = () => {
    return(
        <View 
            style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                top: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                alignItems:"center",
                flex:1,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.02)'
            }} 
            pointerEvents={'none'}>
                <View style={{backgroundColor:"rgba(0,0,0,.5)",borderRadius:scale(5), padding:scale(20)}}>
                    <ActivityIndicator color={"#fff"} size={"large"} />
                </View>
        </View>
    )
}

export default BlockLoading
```